# Creating a UDF that returns that returns a formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA and have been reading all about user defined functions and macros. I'm hoping someone could help me out with a project.

I have a subscription to a service that pulls information into excel using an add-in in the ribbon. The only way to pull in the formula is to either 1) use the ribbon which involves a lot of clicking and waiting or 2)type in the formula into the cell with also takes times.

On excel, for normal functions (i.e. if, find, text), I often use the tab shortcut to fill out the formulas. I would like to to create a formula in excel (using VBA) so that I can write "=" -then hit tab - then reference a cell - and then the formula takes the referenced cell and returns a formula.

FYI - I am using Windows 7 and Office 2013

For example:

- IF cell A1 the input number = 12345
- In Cell B1 I enter the Comm formula that pulls in the data = "=ABC(A1,"Value_Name")
- Cell B1 will display = ZYZYZYZY (which comes from the subscription database)

How do I write a VBA code that basically does:

```
Function (Value)
Returns =ABC(Value,"Value_Name") 
: Which then calls the comm function and returns ZYZYZYZY
End Function
```

I tried my best to explain what I am trying to do - apologies if it was difficult to follow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can call the other function using `Application.Run`:

```
Public Function MyUDF(Value As Variant) As Variant
    MyUDF = Application.Run("ABC", Value, "Value_Name")
End Function
```